# Can't print three fields at the same time within a separate method

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I've created a spider to fetch the name, description and status of different items from a website. The spider can scrape the name and description from one place but it has to go another place within the same site to fetch the status.

Following are the steps which represent how to do the whole thing manually, and which also help understand what the logic the script is built upon.

1. Navigate to [this link](https://industrial.omron.de/de/products/nyb) and parse the `ids` and `links connected to ids` from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRQOd.jpg).
2. Use the `ids` to produce json response within which the required status is available.
3. Use the `links connected to ids` to parse name and description from inner pages, as in [this one](https://industrial.omron.de/de/products/NYB17-21001).

The spider is doing fine as long as it prints required information in two different methods `fetch_status()` and `fetch_content()`.

I've tried so far with:

```
import json
import scrapy
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class OmronSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'omron'
    start_urls = ['https://industrial.omron.de/de/products/nyb']
    status_url = 'https://industrial.omron.de/en/api/product_lifecycle_management/search?'

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept': '*/*'
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
        for item in soup.select("table.details > tbody > tr.filtered > td.product-name a"):
            product_id = item.get_text(strip=True)

            product_url = response.urljoin(item.get("href"))
            yield scrapy.Request(product_url,headers=self.headers,callback=self.fetch_content)

            params = {'q': product_id}
            req_url = f'{self.status_url}{urllib.parse.urlencode(params)}'
            yield scrapy.Request(req_url,headers=self.headers,callback=self.fetch_status)

    def fetch_status(self, response):
        item = json.loads(response.text)['data']
        if item:
            yield {"status":item[0]['status']}
        else:
            yield {"status":None}

    def fetch_content(self, response):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
        product_name = soup.select_one("header.page-width > h1").get_text(strip=True)
        description = soup.select_one(".content > p").get_text(strip=True)
        yield {"product_name":product_name,"description":description}
```

***How can I print the three fields, as in `product_name`, `description` and `status` at the same time probably within a separate method?***

Comment: `parse` is the method which is fetching all the results you're looking for right? If so, why `yield` 2 separate times if you want the results together? Also are you sure you want to be using `yield` and not `return`?

Comment: Why not just storing the recieved data all in one variable (a `dict` or a `list` for example) and `yield` that variable?

Comment: I used `yield` twice as I sent two different requests to the different urls. I'm not saying I wish to stick to the logic that I've already applied. Given that I'm ready to follow any better way of achieving the results.

Comment: Do you have an example of a url to get the json the works? I just get a 404 response when I try any of the queries

Comment: You will always get 404 status unless you use this headers `'Accept': '*/*'` or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass data from one callback to another using [`cb_kwargs`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions). Specifically for your case, you want to pass your already parsed data (`product_name` and `description`) to your `fetch_status` method.

An example is below (in testing I saw `status` was always `None` so not sure if further debugging is needed).

A few of extra things I changed:

- Use the inbuilt [`TextResponse.css`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.TextResponse.css) method to select content rather than using `BeautifulSoup` (it is fine to use `bs4` if you feel more comfortable, but `scrapy` has what you need for this example)
- Use [`Response.follow`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.follow) instead of making new `Request`s by hand (has some advantages such as being able to directly take a `Selector` as I've done in the `parse` method)
- Use [`TextResponse.json`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.TextResponse.json) to deserialise the json (just a shortcut instead of importing the `json` module`)

```py
import scrapy
import urllib


class OmronSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "omron"
    start_urls = ["https://industrial.omron.de/de/products/nyb"]
    status_url = (
        "https://industrial.omron.de/en/api/product_lifecycle_management/search?"
    )

    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36",
        "Accept": "*/*",
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        for item in response.css("td.product-name a"):
            yield response.follow(item, callback=self.fetch_content)

    def fetch_content(self, response):
        parsed_data = {
            "product_name": response.css("header.page-width > h1::text").get(),
            "description": response.css(".content > p::text").get(),
        }

        params = {"q": parsed_data["product_name"]}
        yield response.follow(
            f"{self.status_url}{urllib.parse.urlencode(params)}",
            callback=self.fetch_status,
            cb_kwargs=dict(parsed_data=parsed_data),
            headers=self.headers,
        )

    def fetch_status(self, response, parsed_data):
        item = response.json()["data"]
        status = item[0]["status"] if item else None
        yield {**parsed_data, "status": status}
```

Comment: This is so incredibly awesome @tomjn. I planned not to use this [inline_requests](https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-inline-requests/) or `async` and you helped me avoid that.